# How to block elements to wrap on text content?

Tags: html, css, text, block, word-wrap

I have 2 `div`s that I want to position vertically, aligned to the left and I want their width to wrap based on the amount of text.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KmzbP/1/)

```css
.main {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
}

.line {
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: #505050;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="line">Content content content content</div>
  <div class="line">Content content</div>
</div>
```

The reason why I am asking if there is a more straight forward solution is because I think that `width: 0` and `white-space: nowrap` may affect different content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per i understand may be that's you want.

```
.main {
    color: white;
}
.line {
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: #505050;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/2kmzK/1/

Comment: Yes, that's it! I did not know that you can both float and clear and element. By the way, that works without the "white-space" at the end. I'll test it in the browsers and post my findings afterwards.

Comment: Tested it starting from IE7 to modern browsers and it works good. Floating it and clearing it at the same time does the job elegantly.